# Options too long in Jquery's chosen with fixed width

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a chosen select with a fixed width, and it works as expected when an option is selected (the option's text gets cut and an ellipsis appears), but when I click the select field, the options listed are too long and they take several lines.

Is there a way to mimic the behavior of the selected option? that is, showing a list of options with the text cut with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I should've look into it a bit further before asking!
In case anyone is interested, you can override some styles that would allow you to keep the options in one line, with ellipsis in case of text overflow:

```
.chosen-results .active-result{
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```